# fancybox - simulating a mouseclick issue

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am getting 2 different results when invoking fancybox from a click, and a simulated click. The code writes a link into the wrapper, uses that link to trigger the fancybox. That one is fine, it takes all the properties I have set(width, height etc).

The call `$("a#surveypop").fancybox().trigger('click');` does not. Is there a way to pass variables through this call?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#wrapper').append('<a id="surveypop" href="/survey/survey.html"></a>');
  $("a#surveypop").fancybox({
    'height': 965,
    'width': 555,
    'overlayOpacity' : 0.6,
    'overlayColor' : '#000000',
    'scrolling' : "no",
    'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
    'transitionOut'     : 'elastic',
    'type':'iframe'
  });  
});  

function popup_open() {
  $("a#surveypop").fancybox().trigger('click');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Felix Kling (above) mentions, you shouldn't be initializing fancybox again.

All you need to do is simply trigger the link

```
$("a#surveypop").trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `$("a#surveypop").click();` ?

You already setup fancybox with your first call. If you call `fancybox()` again, you reinitialise it with the default values.